# Error in JNLP file when trying to launch app

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

I have a java applications which is developed using Netbean IDE that is need to be start with javaws, when I try to download and run the applications I get following errors,

```
*JNLP1*
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<jnlp href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/launch.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
    <information>
        <title>Basic Application Example</title>
        <vendor>Sun Microsystems Inc.</vendor>
        <homepage href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex"/>
        <description>A simple java desktop application based on Swing Application Framework</description>
        <description kind="short">Basic Application Example</description>
    <icon href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/MnuIcon.gif" kind="default"/>
</information>
<update check="background"/>
<security>
<all-permissions/>
</security>
    <resources>
<j2se version="1.6+"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/OFMEX_MANUFACTURING.jar" main="true"/>
    <jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/AbsoluteLayout.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/activation.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/ant-1.7.1.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/antlr-2.7.5.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/antlr-2.7.6.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/appframework-1.0.3.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/asm-attrs.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/asm.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/barbecue-1.1.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/barbecue-1.5-beta1.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/barcode4j-2.0.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/batik-anim.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/batik-awt-util.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/batik-bridge.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/batik-css.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/batik-dom.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/batik-ext.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/batik-gvt.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/batik-parser.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/batik-script.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/batik-svg-dom.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/batik-svggen.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/batik-util.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/batik-xml.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/bcel-5.2.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/boot.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/bsh-2.0b4.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/castor-1.2.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/cglib-2.1.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/cincom-jr-xmla.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/com-jaspersoft-ireport-addons.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/com-jaspersoft-ireport-components.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/com-jaspersoft-ireport-designer-standalone.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/com-jaspersoft-ireport-heartbeat.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/com-jaspersoft-ireport-jasperserver.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/com-jaspersoft-ireport-samples.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/com-jaspersoft-ireport.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/com-jaspersoft-jrx.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/commons-beanutils-1.8.2.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/commons-collections-2.1.1.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/commons-digester-1.7.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/commons-javaflow-20060411.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/commons-logging-1.1.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/commons-logging-api-1.0.2.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/commons-math-1.0.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/commons-net-1.4.1.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/commons-pool-1.3.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/commons-vfs-1.0.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/core-renderer.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/core.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/core_de.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/core_es.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/core_fr.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/core_ireport.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/core_it.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/core_ja.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/core_nb_de.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/core_nb_es.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/core_nb_it.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/core_nb_ja.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/core_nb_pt_BR.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/core_nb_zh_CN.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/core_nb_zh_TW.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/core_pl.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/core_pt_BR.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/core_sq.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/core_zh_CN.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/core_zh_TW.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/DateChooser.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/ddl.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/dom4j-1.6.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/ehcache-1.1.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/eigenbase-properties-1.1.0.10924.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/eigenbase-properties.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/eigenbase-resgen-1.3.0.11873.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/eigenbase-resgen.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/eigenbase-xom-1.3.0.11999.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/eigenbase-xom.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/ejb3-persistence.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/flexdock-0.4.1.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/groovy-all-1.5.5.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/hibernate-annotations.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/hibernate-commons-annotations.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/hibernate3.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/hsqldb-1.7.1.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/hsqldb-1.8.0-10.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/iReport.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/iText-2.1.7.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/iTextAsian.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/jakarta-bcel-20050813.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/jakarta-oro-2.0.8.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/JasperBabylon-1.0.0.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/jasperreports-3.7.4.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/jasperreports-applet-3.7.4.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/jasperreports-chart-themes-3.7.3.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/jasperreports-extensions-3.5.3.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/jasperreports-fonts-3.7.4.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/jasperreports-javaflow-3.7.4.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/javacup.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/javassist-3.4.GA.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/jaxb-api.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/jaxb-impl.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/jaxb-xjc.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/jaxen-1.1.1.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/jcmdline-1.0.2.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/jcommon-1.0.0.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/jcommon-1.0.15.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/jdt-compiler-3.1.1.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/jfreechart-1.0.12.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/jh-2.0_05.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/jna-3.0.9.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/jpa.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/js_activation-1.1.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/js_axis-1.4patched.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/js_commons-codec-1.3.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/js_commons-discovery-0.2.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/js_commons-httpclient-3.1.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/js_jasperserver-common-ws-3.5.0.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/js_jaxrpc.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/js_mail-1.4.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/js_saaj-api-1.3.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/js_wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/jsmoothgen-ant-0.9.7.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/jsr173_api.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/jta.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/junit-4.5.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/jxl-2.6.10.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/jxl-2.6.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/log4j-1.2.9.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/looks-2.0-rc.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/mail.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/microba-0.4.1-bin.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/mondrian-2.3.2.8944.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/mondrian-3.1.1.12687.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/nsisant-1.1.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/png-encoder-1.5.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/poi-3.0.1-FINAL-20070705.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/poi-3.5-FINAL-20090928.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/poi-3.6.jar
</resources>
    <application-desc main
jnlp file truncated after 10K
```

Exception:

```
JNLParseException[ Could not parse launch file. Error at line 0.]
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.updateFinalLaunchDesc(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

---

Wrapped Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parseXMLElement(Unknown Source)
```

.....

How do I solve this problem?

this is my launch.jnlp, but JNLP1 is shown in the error message,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<jnlp codebase="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/." href="launch.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
    <information>
        <title>Basic Application Example</title>
        <vendor>Sun Microsystems Inc.</vendor>
        <homepage href="http://appframework.dev.java.net"/>
        <description>A simple java desktop application based on Swing Application Framework</description>
        <description kind="short">Basic Application Example</description>
    <icon href="MnuIcon.gif" kind="default"/>
</information>
<update check="background"/>
<security>
<all-permissions/>
</security>
    <resources>
<j2se version="1.6+"/>
<jar href="OFMEX_MANUFACTURING.jar" main="true"/>
    <jar href="lib/AbsoluteLayout.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/activation.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/ant-1.7.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/antlr-2.7.5.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/antlr-2.7.6.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/appframework-1.0.3.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/asm-attrs.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/asm.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/barbecue-1.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/barbecue-1.5-beta1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/barcode4j-2.0.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/batik-anim.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/batik-awt-util.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/batik-bridge.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/batik-css.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/batik-dom.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/batik-ext.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/batik-gvt.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/batik-parser.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/batik-script.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/batik-svg-dom.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/batik-svggen.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/batik-util.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/batik-xml.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/bcel-5.2.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/boot.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/bsh-2.0b4.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/castor-1.2.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/cglib-2.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/cincom-jr-xmla.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/com-jaspersoft-ireport-addons.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/com-jaspersoft-ireport-components.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/com-jaspersoft-ireport-designer-standalone.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/com-jaspersoft-ireport-heartbeat.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/com-jaspersoft-ireport-jasperserver.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/com-jaspersoft-ireport-samples.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/com-jaspersoft-ireport.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/com-jaspersoft-jrx.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/commons-beanutils-1.8.2.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/commons-collections-2.1.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/commons-digester-1.7.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/commons-javaflow-20060411.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/commons-logging-1.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/commons-logging-api-1.0.2.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/commons-math-1.0.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/commons-net-1.4.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/commons-pool-1.3.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/commons-vfs-1.0.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/core-renderer.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/core.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/core_de.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/core_es.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/core_fr.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/core_ireport.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/core_it.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/core_ja.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/core_nb_de.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/core_nb_es.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/core_nb_it.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/core_nb_ja.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/core_nb_pt_BR.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/core_nb_zh_CN.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/core_nb_zh_TW.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/core_pl.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/core_pt_BR.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/core_sq.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/core_zh_CN.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/core_zh_TW.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/DateChooser.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/ddl.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/dom4j-1.6.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/ehcache-1.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/eigenbase-properties-1.1.0.10924.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/eigenbase-properties.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/eigenbase-resgen-1.3.0.11873.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/eigenbase-resgen.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/eigenbase-xom-1.3.0.11999.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/eigenbase-xom.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/ejb3-persistence.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/flexdock-0.4.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/groovy-all-1.5.5.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/hibernate-annotations.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/hibernate-commons-annotations.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/hibernate3.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/hsqldb-1.7.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/hsqldb-1.8.0-10.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/iReport.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/iText-2.1.7.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/iTextAsian.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jakarta-bcel-20050813.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jakarta-oro-2.0.8.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/JasperBabylon-1.0.0.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jasperreports-3.7.4.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jasperreports-applet-3.7.4.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jasperreports-chart-themes-3.7.3.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jasperreports-extensions-3.5.3.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jasperreports-fonts-3.7.4.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jasperreports-javaflow-3.7.4.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/javacup.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/javassist-3.4.GA.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jaxb-api.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jaxb-impl.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jaxb-xjc.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jaxen-1.1.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jcmdline-1.0.2.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jcommon-1.0.0.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jcommon-1.0.15.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jdt-compiler-3.1.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jfreechart-1.0.12.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jh-2.0_05.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jna-3.0.9.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jpa.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/js_activation-1.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/js_axis-1.4patched.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/js_commons-codec-1.3.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/js_commons-discovery-0.2.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/js_commons-httpclient-3.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/js_jasperserver-common-ws-3.5.0.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/js_jaxrpc.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/js_mail-1.4.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/js_saaj-api-1.3.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/js_wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jsmoothgen-ant-0.9.7.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jsr173_api.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jta.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/junit-4.5.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jxl-2.6.10.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jxl-2.6.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/log4j-1.2.9.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/looks-2.0-rc.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/mail.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/microba-0.4.1-bin.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/mondrian-2.3.2.8944.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/mondrian-3.1.1.12687.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/nsisant-1.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/png-encoder-1.5.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/poi-3.0.1-FINAL-20070705.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/poi-3.5-FINAL-20090928.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/poi-3.6.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/rex-20070125.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/rhino-1.7R1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/saaj-api-1.3.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/serializer.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/servlet.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/spring-2.0-m2.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/spring-beans-2.5.5.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/spring-context-2.0-m2.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/spring-core-2.5.5.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/spring-hibernate3-2.0-m2.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/sqleonardo-2007.03.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/swing-worker-1.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/swingx-2007_05_13.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/tinylaf.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/toniclf.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/xalan-2.7.1.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/xalan.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/xercesImpl-2.7.0.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/xercesImpl.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/xml-apis-ext.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/xml-apis.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/swing-layout-1.0.4.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/poi-3.5-FINAL-20090928.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jcalendar-1.4.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jasperreports-4.0.2.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jasperreports-chart-themes-4.0.2.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jasperreports-fonts-4.0.2.jar"/>
<jar href="lib/jfreechart-1.0.14.jar"/>
</resources>
    <application-desc main-class="COMMON.FrmSplashScreen">
    </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/poi-3.5-FINAL-20090928.jar"/>
<jar href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/lib/poi-3.6.jar
</resources>
    <application-desc main
jnlp file truncated after 10K
```

1. Is that `jar` element for `poi-3.6.jar` well formed in the JNLP?
2. I suspect all the problems are related to the `jnlp file truncated after 10K`.  It might be necessary to move some of the archives to extensions.  Better, since that amounts to 143 archives prior to even the broken element, seriously review if you need that plethora of Jars on the run-time class-path of the app. in the first place.  It appears to be an ***huge*** application to download.

Either way, be sure to check the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).  That might reveal other errors.

---

BTW, changing the JNLP element from ..

```
<jnlp href="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex/launch.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
```

..to..

```
<jnlp codebase="http://192.168.1.200/ofmex" href="launch.jnlp" spec="1.0+">
```

.. And then removing `http://192.168.1.200/ofmex` from ***every*** other HREF in the JNLP shown, reduces the size considerably.

```
Old  9879
New  5950
```

---

I did not notice your edit as I was posting my answer.  This part is specific to the complete JNLP.

Again, there are a lot of suspicious elements to that JNLP.  As some examples:

#### 1. Repeated versions of the same API.

```
<jar href="lib/jfreechart-1.0.12.jar"/>
// ..much later..
<jar href="lib/jfreechart-1.0.14.jar"/>
```

It seems the first would be used, but why are both mentioned?

#### 2. RC and beta Jars.

```
<jar href="lib/looks-2.0-rc.jar"/>
...
<jar href="lib/barbecue-1.5-beta1.jar"/>
```

#### 3. Binary archives in jar elements.

```
<jar href="lib/microba-0.4.1-bin.jar"/>
...
<jar href="lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.12-bin.jar"/>
```

If those Jars actually contain natives, they should be mentioned in a `nativelib` element and put in an OS specific resources section.

#### 4. The 'What could you possibly need this for in a client app.' category?

This category has me scratching my head as to why you'd need these APIs in a rich client desk-top application, or at least why you'd need them in a desk-top client that requires 1.6+.

```
<jar href="lib/servlet.jar"/>
..
<jar href="lib/swing-worker-1.1.jar"/>  // has been in J2SE since 1.6
..
<jar href="lib/swing-layout-1.0.4.jar"/> // probably has been in J2SE since 1.2
..
<jar href="lib/junit-4.5.jar"/>
```

Comment: I made an edit to my answer.  Please do not reply to it until you can confirm that you have checked the JNLP using JaNeLA.

Comment: +1 Related to `jfreechart `, I see two different versions of `jcommon`.

Comment: @trashgod  "The more you look.."  While the ultimate answer will probably be had by making some extensions (I'm guessing ***each*** JNLP can be as long as 10Kb), it could not hurt to rationalize the class-path at the same time.

Comment: Did this help solve the problem?  If not, say so.  If so, accept it.